# Can not display image in table view cell using firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I can not display image using firebase in table view cell, I don't know why because my code seems to work, but not there, may anyone help me?

Note: The label Works. I created a custom cell using a cocoa touch class, then I have linked that using the notation to cell as you can see.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase



class PlacesTableViewController: UIViewController, 
UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
let ref = Database.database().reference()
var PlacesRef:DatabaseReference! = nil
var SelectedRef:DatabaseReference! = nil
let storage = Storage.storage()
var postdata:[String] = [String]()



@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    print("Here Variables")
    print("Here translated Names")
    PlacesRef = ref.child("Places")
    let storageRef = self.storage.reference()
    PlacesRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for a in ((snapshot.value as AnyObject).allKeys)!{
                var now:String = ""
                self.postdata.append(a as! String)

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("we don't have that, add it to the DB now")
        }

        print(self.postdata) //add key to array
    }
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
}




func tableView(_ _tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection selection: Int) ->Int{
    print(postdata)

    return postdata.count
}


func tableView( _ tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
   let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    var image=UIImage()
    let StorageRef = storage.reference()
    let NationRef = StorageRef.child("Nations/\(postdata[indexPath.row]).jpg")
    print("\(postdata[indexPath.row]).jpg")
    NationRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
            image = UIImage(data: data!)!
            print("image downloaded!")
        }
    }



    cell.DetailLabel.text = postdata[indexPath.row]
    cell.DetailImage.image = image
    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: Lack of relevant tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what happens in

```
func tableView( _ tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
   let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    var image=UIImage()
    let StorageRef = storage.reference()
    let NationRef = StorageRef.child("Nations/\(postdata[indexPath.row]).jpg")

// HERE we starting async web request for image data   (tag 1)      

    NationRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            // HERE we getting image data from async request and storing it in image var (tag 3) 
            image = UIImage(data: data!)!
            print("image downloaded!")
        }
    }

    cell.DetailLabel.text = postdata[indexPath.row]

    // HERE we setting UIImage to cell's imageView  (tag 2)  
    cell.DetailImage.image = image
    return cell
}
```

if printing tags we'll get tag 1, tag 2 and tag 3. It means that firstly you create empty uiimage, then set this image to cell's imageView and at last you change image to image from request (image, not cell's imageView)

I think the answer can be - replace *image = UIImage(data: data!)!* with *cell.DetailImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)*

and there are many ways to improve this method